# Pythonic and compact way to compare the key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Just want to know a good way how to do this:

```
a = {'key':'value'}
if 'key' in a:
    if a['key'] == 'value':
        # do something ...
```

The problem is sometimes I need to handle cases whe `"key"` is actually `"@key"`, So I don't want to duplicate the same code with `if '@key' in a: ....`

So the question is how to handle both cases in most Pythonic and more compact way?

Comment: Can't you just strip all leading `@` before inserting data into dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a function like `a.get('key')` that checks more than one key. Therefore, I would write that general function. That's the most pythonic way, in my opinion, and leads to the most compact and readable code when you use it.

1) Here's one way:

```
def dget(d, keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        try: return d[key]
        except KeyError: pass
    return default

...

a = {'key':'value'}
if dget(a, ['key', '@key']) == 'value':
    #do something
```

2) You could be less general if you always want to look for exactly 'key' and '@key'.

```
def dget(d, key, default=None):
    return d.get(key,d.get('@' + key, default))

...

a = {'key':'value'}
if dget(a, 'key') == 'value':
    #do something
```

3) Finally, you could extend the dict class. You would rewrite the `get` method, so that you could just

```
a = mydict()
a['key'] = 'value'
if a.get(['key', '@key']) == 'value':
   #do something
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I would go about doing this:

```
a = {'key':'value'}
if any(a.get(key, None) == 'value' for key in ('key','@key')):
    # do something ...
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
if a.get('key', a.get('@key', None)) == 'value':
```

This combines both keys (and gets rid of the slightly non-Pythonic use of `if... in...` followed by `a['key']`).

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to create a function which will act as a holder for the code (well, that's more or less what functions are for):

```
a = {'key':'value'}

def handle(key):
    if key in a:
        if a[key] == 'value':
            # do something...

handle('key')
handle('@key')
```

This will be a good solution if you actually have to do something with `key` (like for example update existing entry).

Answer (score 1):

If you have more potential patterns than just 'key' and '@key', you could use a regex on each key and test the value:

```
import re

a = {'key':'value', '@key':'value', '#key':'value', 'k':'value', 'key2':'val'}
print [k for k,v in a.items() if re.search(r'.?key',k) and v=='value']
# ['@key', '#key', 'key']
```